# Is there a standard interface connector or layout for MSP430's "Spy-Bi-Wire" (SBW) interface?

Tags: msp430, jtag

Is there some standard order and/or footprint that people use for these 4 pins? Something akin to the standard 2x3 6-pin ISP layout for AVR chips?

Comment: I think the document to read is [MSP430 Hardware Tools User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau278ah/slau278ah.pdf?ts=1663048054990&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.at%252F). See pages 22 and 23.

Comment: @jonk I've seen that note, but it only seems to talk about the electrical connections and not the physical connection. Is there some pad layout that is typically used for these 4 pins that most MSP430 people would look at and say "Ah, this is where I can make a SBW connection to this board!"? For AVRs, the 2x3 ISP connector is nearly universal. Thanks!

Comment: So far, the target boards I have here using MSP430 use the 2x7 header, as shown. If you look at the [MSP FET](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-FET#tech-docs) tool, you will see that they support SBW but they support it over a 14-pin cable. (To a 2x7 header.) In fact, they don't provide any other programming cable with the product. Yet they support SBW (2 and 4 wire, I believe.) I can't speak for TI. Obviously. But that's pretty much what you find from their professional (and hobbyist) programming tools. Do you see any with a different cable provided?

Answer (score 0):

TI uses this 4x1 SBW pad layout...

[image]

(0.1" (2.54mm) spacing)

[image]

...in this reference design...

https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-REMOTE-CONTROLLER-FOR-AC